# I want uTorrent to use one ISP, and all other applications to use another ISP

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, isp

I have a Windows 7 based desktop with two LAN cards (NICs):

**NIC1** is connected to a router, which connects to a reliable ISP with a low data cap (Fair Usage Policy).

**NIC2** is connected to an ADSL modem, which connects to an unreliable ISP with no data cap.

I want to keep both NICs enabled and connected in such a way that uTorrent only uses NIC2, while all other applications use NIC1. Is this possible within Windows? I use Comodo's firewall, could that (or any other third party firewall) be configured in some way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I am aware of natively, however running a virtual machine with access to just NIC 2 would achieve the same result.

In the networking settings you can set the priority of the network cards so you just setup N1C 1 to be top priority and your normal traffic will go that way.

Alternatively qBittorrent allows you to select the network interface to use:

http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/